# Wsdl2.js doesn't take json data in to the accoutn

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have just installed package [wsdl2.js](https://github.com/holidayextras/wsdl2.js/blob/master/README.md) via npm and now i wan't to use is.
I'm having problems with my json data, since it's always empty.

Here is my code test 1

```
var Service = require('/home/valor/development/test/User');

var json = {subscriberUid : 'd7f3ea63-1118-44bb-ba97-f6f0c417313a'};
requestT = new Service.UserSoapServiceBeanPort.getSubscriber(json);
requestT.debug();
console.log(json);
requestT.request(function(err, response) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

and failed response because json is empty since subscriberUid is a must

```
{
  "method": "getSubscriber",
  "type": "Request",
  "json": {},
  "xml": "<getSubscriber></getSubscriber>",
  "validates": true
}
{ subscriberUid: 'd7f3ea63-1118-44bb-ba97-f6f0c417313a' }
{
  "method": "getSubscriber",
  "took": 92
}
{ '0': 'Invalid response to getSubscriber' }

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then i have tried to do it this way as explained in tutorial / example
test2

```
var Service = require('/home/valor/development/test/User');

requestT = new Service.UserSoapServiceBeanPort.getSubscriber();
requestT.subscriberUid = 'd7f3ea63-1118-44bb-ba97-f6f0c417313a';
requestT.debug();
requestT.request(function(err, response) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

and again failed response

```
/usr/local/bin/node test.js
{
  "method": "getSubscriber",
  "type": "Request",
  "json": {},
  "xml": "<getSubscriber></getSubscriber>",
  "validates": true
}
{
  "method": "getSubscriber",
  "took": 90
}
{ '0': 'Invalid response to getSubscriber' }

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Test 3

```
var service = require("/home/valor/development/test/user");
service.Settings.debugSoap = true;

var request = new service.UserSoapServiceBeanPort.getSubscriber();
console.log(request);
console.log(request.subscriberUid = 'd7f3ea63-1118-44bb-ba97-f6f0c417313a');
request.subscriberUid = 'd7f3ea63-1118-44bb-ba97-f6f0c417313a'
request.debug();
```

Response

```
/usr/local/bin/node test.js
{ getSubscriber: [Getter/Setter] }
d7f3ea63-1118-44bb-ba97-f6f0c417313a
{
  "method": "getSubscriber",
  "type": "Request",
  "json": {},
  "xml": "<getSubscriber></getSubscriber>",
  "validates": true
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

One more strange thing i found is

```
console.log(Service.UserSoapServiceBeanPort.getSubscriber);
[Function]
```

while

```
console.log(Service.UserSoapServiceBeanPort.getSubscriber());
undefined
```

Now i don't know what else can i do, so i hope you guys can help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with wsdl2.js developers, we figure it out that wsdl2.js doesn't have support to convert our WSDL in working code, because is slightly different from standard one. We use xs:elements, while wsdl2.js can convert xsd:elements